# jquery on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have little problem

on form submit

```
e.preventDefault();
```

not working

code:

```
$(function(){

    $("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
        Validation.init({
            name : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='name']").val(),
            phone : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='mobile']").val(),
            mail : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='email']").val(),
            text : $("#contact-form").find("textarea").val()
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

after submit page reloading :(

HTML

```
 <form id = "contact-form" action = "" method = "post">
        <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder="სახელი">
        <input type = "text" name = "mobile" placeholder="მობილურის ნომერი">
        <input type = "text" name = "email" placeholder="ემაილი">
        <textarea name = "text" placeholder = "ტექსტი" ></textarea>
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "გაგზავნა">
     </form>
```

i think problem is

```
 Validation.init({
            name : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='name']").val(),
            phone : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='mobile']").val(),
            mail : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='email']").val(),
            text : $("#contact-form").find("textarea").val()
        });
```

Comment: Will need your HTML code.

Comment: Place your html too! What is your submit button?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Please post the generated HTML, not the PHP one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pxXxh/ your code seems fine. Check if your `$("#contact-form").submit(` is ever executed

Comment: try `return false;` instead of `e.preventdefault();`.

Comment: @drinchev Your code works because you have `Validation` defined.

Comment: @GiaNebieridze Post your generated HTML, source in browser.

Comment: I assume that `Validation` sub is working ... since we examined that everything is fine with `event.preventDefault()` the OP has to check out his Validation function for errors. And he might want to start a new question about this, because as I can see everyone here is puzzle-minded about something that actually works ... e.g. `event.preventDefault()!`

Comment: @GiaNebieridze Try running the app in CHrome and see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue: `Validation` is not defined, so your code exits before it reaches `preventDefault()`.

Call `preventDefault()` before validation.

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Validation.init({
        name : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='name']").val(),
        phone : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='mobile']").val(),
        mail : $("#contact-form").find("input[name='email']").val(),
        text : $("#contact-form").find("textarea").val()
    });
});
```

Now, you will get an error message, debug the error to fix your issue.